# Does every element of the empty list posses every property?

Tags: logic, notation

Suppose we have a list of elements $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$.

Then, as I've understood, setting $n=0$ above results in the empty list $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_0$ of no elements (please correct me if I'm **wrong** ).

Now does every element of the empty list posses every property $P(x)$ ?

I know that $x \in \emptyset \Rightarrow P(x)$ is true for every $x$. However, a list is not set ?

As an example:

$v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n \in V$ is linearly independent if $c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \ldots + c_n v_n = 0 \Rightarrow c_i=0$.

Are $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_0$ linearly independent then ?

I know this might be a "stupid" question, but I've been wondering ...

Comment: What is the difference between empty list and empty set?

Comment: I don't know. If they are equal, then the elements of the empty list are linearly independent ?

Comment: $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_0$? If you mean the empty sequence, why do you write it like this, what about $()$?

Comment: Take a linearly independent set. Any subset of it is linearly independent? $\emptyset$ is subset of...

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen The empty tuple is linearly independent and so is the empty set. It's the basis of the trivial vector space.

Comment: But the elements of $()$ are also linearly dependent ?

Comment: This is by definition @user2345215 ?

Comment: Why are people insisting on the vector space? It's not the crux of the question at all.

Comment: @GitGud I disagree, sometimes the empty cases are specifically excluded (connectedness), but not for vector spaces, because the empty basis is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of linear independence can be written as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i=0\implies c_i=0\text{ for all }i$$
There's almost no difference in considering $v_i$'s as a tuple or as a set (considering them as a tuple simplifies certain arguments).

It should be clear the empty tuple $()$ or the empty set $\varnothing$ of vectors satisfies the definition, as the empty sum is $0$ and all of the (empty set) of scalars are equal to $0$.

This is useful because then all vector spaces have a basis (the trivial vector space $\{0\}$ can only have empty bases).

Comment: Why are all of the empty set of scalars equal to $0$ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: So you are saying $c_i \in \emptyset \Rightarrow c_i = 0$ is true, so you conclude that $c_i = 0$ ? But this is just an implication being true. I could also say that $c_i \neq 0$ and this is true as well ? So we can conclude that $()$ is both linear dependent and independent ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen No! The statement is $i\in\varnothing\implies c_i=0$. There's no $c_i$ as there's no $i$. The negation would be $\exists i: i\in\varnothing\land c_i\ne 0$, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: But if there is no $ c_i $ why is it then $0$ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen You can't conclude $c_i=0$, the implication being true means (by definition) that either $i\in\varnothing$ is false or $c_i=0$ is true. Clearly $i\in\varnothing$ is false, so you can't conclude $c_i=0$.

Comment: But if you cant conclude whether they are $0$ - how can you then say there is linear independence ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen But they are! All of the $c_i$ are $0$, all of them are also $-1, \pi, \infty$ at the same time. Additionally, they are all elephants. I'm **not** joking.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that $() $ are both linearly independent as well ss dependent then ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen No it doesn't mean that. The negation of "all cows are dead" is not "all cows are alive", but "there's a cow which is alive"!

Comment: So just to be sure. You say "all of the $c_i$ are $0$, also $1$ and so on". Why can we then say the only linear combination satisfies $c_i = 0$ ? This is the requirement, right ? Well, also $c_i = 1$, so there is not a unique linear combination of $0$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18655/discussion-between-user2345215-and-nicolas-lykke-iversen).

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Nevermind, I forgot the chat doesn't support MathJax, so I won't continue there. So let me repeat it: This is not a rhetoric exercise, everything has a precise meaning. I'm afraid I need to go deeper into the mathematical logic and set theory: By $(c_i)_{i\in I}$ we mean a function $f:I\to\mathbb R$, i.e. a some (possibly empty) set of pairs $(i, r)$ satisfying certain properties, where $i\in I$ and $r\in\mathbb R$. **Question**: How many functions $f:\varnothing\to\mathbb R$ are there?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Now imagine $f:I\to V$ is given (represents vectors $v_i$). The linear independence then means $(\forall g:I\to\mathbb R)(\sum_{i\in I}g(i)f(i)=0\implies(\forall i\in I)(f(i)=0))$. The function $g$ represents constants $c_i$ and you should be able to see this formula is true when $I=\varnothing$. That exactly means the negation of this formula (linear dependence) is false. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Think of your list as a function $f:I\to S$ for index set $I\subset \mathbb{N}$ and arbitrary set $S$.

An empty list corresponds to $I=\emptyset$. It would then be vacuously true that $\forall x\in I: P(f(x))$, i.e. every element of the list has property P.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every element in the empty list possesses every property you can think of. Even the property $P(x)$ saying that $x$ is not an element of the empty list. So it is correct to say that every element on the empty list is not on the empty list.

And yes, the empty list of vectors is linearly independent in every vector space, and a basis in every $0$ dimensional vector spaces, i.e., every vector space consisting of just the $0$ vector.

Comment: But then we can say that empty list of vectors is linearly dependent too ? And what is your argument that we can say that every element of the empty list posses every property ?

Comment: No, the empty list of vectors is not linearly dependent since to be linearly dependent you should be able to express $0$ as a non-trivial linear combination of no vectors. Can you do that? As for the argument that every element on the empty list possesses property $P$, can you show me one that does not?